# Pushing data to nodeJS from OSX application

Tags: c++, node.js, network-programming, openframeworks

I've got an OSX application written in c++ (in particular, built with OpenFrameworks) and a server written using nodejs.

The application tracks an object wandering around a room and I want to send information about the object's position to the server on a relatively constant (at least 3 times a second) basis.

From what I can tell I either need a protocol with minimal amounts of setup overhead, or the ability to open up a persistant connection that I can push to.  In case you can't tell - I'm not a network programming guru!  Does anyone know of libraries on either the node.js side and the C++ side that can accomplish this without a 5 million second latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the openFrameworks side you have quite a bunch of possibilities to send data:
(Given current OF 007)
look at the following examples, if they fit your needs:

```
<OF-folder>/apps/addonsExamples/networkTcpClientExample
<OF-folder>/apps/addonsExamples/networkUdpSenderExample
<OF-folder>/apps/addonsExamples/oscSenderExample
```

For node.js, just define a basic socket or something like that to handle the request

```
Here is an example of a simple TCP server which listens
on port 1337 and echoes whatever    you send it:

var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write("Echo server\r\n");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

(pulled from the nods.js frontpage http://nodejs.org/)